# How to change programmatically the input device in the sound preferences of Gnome?

Tags: audio, gnome, input

In a shell script, I would like to change the selection of the input device (i.e. "Choose a device for sound input") in the "Input" tab of the "Sound Preferences" in Gnome.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly "pacmd set-default-source" works if you are using pulseaudio, for example:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_0819_9F13DC90-02-U0x46d0x819.analog-mono
```

Find the source name using "pacmd list-source".